# Api's to get Password Policy in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, passwords, password-policy

I need API's to get Password Policy of Azure Active Directory with help of domain name or with users mailId

Comment: Are you asking about the self service password reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Azure AD password policies from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts). And it is used for **Azure AD user**, but not external users.

There is no method about both Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph API for external users.

For more details, see [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) and [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

---

> Is there any API's to get Password Policy for Azure AD user.

You could use Microsoft Graph:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}?$select=displayName,passwordPolicies
```

The result will look like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(displayName,passwordPolicies)/$entity",
    "displayName": "xxxxxx",
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

You can find details about this property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties).

[image]

There is another way to use [`Get-MsolPasswordPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msolpasswordpolicy?view=azureadps-1.0) by Powershell.

Comment: I need to find a password policy for the Azure AD user. Is there any **API's** to get **Password Policy** for **Azure AD user**.

Comment: @Ragav Yes. I edit my answer and add the API of getting Password Policy.

Comment: Is it possible to get Azure AD users password policies details like character allowed, characters not allowed, Password restrictions, Password expiry, and so on.

Comment: @Ragav I'm afraid that there is no method to get the details. You could see the details in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts).

Comment: As for as i know, There is no api for getting password policy