# How to read password policies in azure ad domain through microsoft graph api

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to read password policies properties of a domain in azure ad if password policies are multiples than want to find users in that domain which fall under that policy

I want api to get these details and an answer from you in details that it is possible ?

Note -> Need to be able to programmatically check the organization's password expiration policy. Specifically referring to the policy managed in the GUI here: admin.microsoft.com -> Settings -> Org Settings ->Security & privacy -> Password expiration policy.

It seems like the only way to do this currently is with an old MSOnline commandlet, but given its imminent deprecation, this needs to be translated to graph.

Comment: What have you done so far, share your piece of code or are you looking for someone to do your task instead of you?!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below **MSOnline commandlet** to get organization's password expiration policy details.

```
Connect-MsolService
Get-MsolPasswordPolicy -DomainName xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get **same results** using Microsoft Graph API, you can run below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains/Mxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can also get same results using below **Microsoft Graph PowerShell** command:

```
Connect-MgGraph
Get-MgDomain -DomainId xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

For getting password policies of **Azure AD users** from Graph API, you can check the below reference:

[Api's to get Password Policy in Azure AD - Stack Overflow by **unknown**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231986/apis-to-get-password-policy-in-azure-ad)

Comment: can u plz tell me how to retrieve all password policies in azure ad domain  through graph api and also i want to make a list of users which fall under these policies ?

Comment: Could you include what `MSOnline` commands you are using to get required results by editing your question? Based on that, I'll update my answer with Graph commands!

Comment: i am using microsoft graph api. I did not want to use powershell commands